# Synchronisation in id3

Tags: audio, id3

I am not clear about synchronisation and unsynchronisation in id3 tags.

I have read the developer info, but i could not able to understand.

Can you please help me in explaining the things clearly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What more precisely you do not understand? It seems [documentation](http://www.id3.org) is quite clear. The synchronisation can be used to some (in general legasy) programs, that do not know about ID3v2, does not accept tag data as frame header. By the way, it seems majority of programs does not use syncronisation, and possible if you faced with dificulties with synchronisation you can try do not work with synchronized tags.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your help. 

Let me put my understanding here, correct me if am wrong. 

There will be a sync signal (Probably starts with FF **). This is used by the decoders for playing the file. 

id3 tag parser, whenever encounters any false sync in id3 tag (byte with MSB - 1), it adds the zero byte following the false sync. 

So the mp3 decoder (without knowledge of id3) would not be able to identify the false sync and would not get by the false sync.

Thanks.

Comment: * would not get "disturbed" by the false sync.

Comment: "id3 tag parser, whenever encounters..." - parser should remove zero byte (replaces 0x00FF with 0xFF: "if (*(WORD*) pbtCurrPos == 0x00FF)"). It is tag writer adds zero byte during unsycronization. And yes, it is for decoder does not interpret tag's data as mp3 frame header.

Comment: And it is probably will be useful to have some test suite. It seems something is here (http://www.getid3.org/samples/index.php) present.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to explain the unsynchronization scheme in a writeup here. In addition to the specifications you might want to have a look at http://phoxis.org/2010/05/08/what-are-id3-tags-all-about/#unsyncsafe